# Time-series database with php

Tags: redis, time-series, rrdtool, rethinkdb, tempodb

Currently I'm using rrdtool to create time-series based databases & charts with php and i'm lately moving to laravel and porting my code.

Is there any existing library for php that can work with redis,mongodb, rethinkdb or tempo-db that can help me create time-series databases like in rrdtool?

Comment: you can maybe try Graphite, it's awesome for time series. I don't know  a specific PHP client, but it should be trivial to push to it, either directly or via Statsd. http://architects.dzone.com/articles/python-getting-data-graphite

Comment: you could just use rrdtool ...

Answer (score 2):

You may want to give a try to [**influxdb**](http://influxdb.org), that's the closer thing to rrdtool & graphite.

> An open-source distributed time series database with no external
>   dependencies. InfluxDB is the new home for all of your metrics,
>   events, and analytics.

Answer (score 0):

[Predis](https://github.com/nrk/predis) is a flexible and feature-complete Redis client library for PHP (>=5.3).

Is recommended by the [Redis Client List](http://redis.io/clients) as mature and supported.

I have been using for a while with no problems at all.